# Oracle - v$sql determine if sql command was commited

Tags: oracle

As we all know `v$sql` / `v$sql_text` / `v$sqlarea` etc.
contains a list of sql commands recently executed.

Well, I would like to know if the transaction that executed a certain sql command was rollbacked/commited or possibly still going, and possibly also know the commit time.

I tried joining it with v$session etc., But couldn't find anything useful.
Help will be appreciated.

Another thing that may help me if there is some way to look at `v$sql` as transactional. That is, only when the transaction that ran the sql command is commited, the information is visible to other sessions in the v$sql table.

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

You omitted the basic question: what are you actually trying to achieve?

`v$sql` views are based on `x$` tables, which are not transactional. To determine if a currently executed transaction has committed, you can use transaction guard. But in general the application should know very well if the transaction completed or rolled back.